# Adding a column which counts number of occurrences of record

Tags: sql, oracle

Is it possible to populate a column in SQL that looks like this? Original column on the left, the one I want on the right.

```
A...1
B...1
C...1
D...1
A...2
C...2
E...1
A...3
D...2
```

i.e. the first occurrence of each letter is 1, the second occurrence of each letter (going down) is a 2, the third occurrence of each letter is a 3 etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  SELECT col1,
  ROW_NUMBER( ) OVER (PARTITION BY
  col1 ORDER BY col1
  NULLS LAST) SRLNO
  FROM table;
```

Replace col1 with 'column name'

and

table with 'table name'